# Why -ian instead of -ien and -üan instead of -üen?

Tags: pinyin

Why are words like 天、面、先、盐 romanized in pinyin as tian, mian, xian, and yan, even though the ending is pronounced [iɛn], and would be better represented as -ien? Likewise, why are words like 卷、全、选、元 romanized as juan, quan, xuan, and yuan, when the final is pronounced [yɛn] and would be better represented as -uen? (at least the way northern Chinese people pronounce it – it seems that southern Chinese people pronounce it as [yan])

Is it that those words actually were pronounced with a [ian] and [yan] final in the past? That doesn't seem like a complete explanation, as Wade-Giles uses -ien, and Wade-Giles is from 1892 (although it does use -üan and not -üen).

Comment: Simply different design, many writing system/language has more than one romanization/latin-based writing solution

Comment: This is not an answer, but please note that pinyin **-en** (本、恩、etc) corresponds to **/-ən/** and not **/-ɛn/**. Basically, whatever combinations of letters you try to use for that rime, you will run into inconsistencies with some other established rime.

Comment: Before you rail at pinyin, look up a poem called "The Chaos" from Gerard Nolst Trenité and rather rail at English!

Comment: @droooze Pinyin already has a rule that -iê /iɛ/ is written -ie, so it wouldn't add another inconsistency to have -iên /iɛn/ → -ien.

Comment: @Pedroski aɪ noʊ, ɪf ˈoʊnli wi kʊd ɹid ænd ɹaɪt ˈɛvɹiθɪŋ ɪn IPA

Comment: @MiCl I'm not concerned about *adding* an inconsistency with any proposal, rather does the proposal *remove* an inconsistency?

Comment: Instead of having two inconsistencies (1. -ian is pronounced [iɛn] instead of [ian]. 2. -ie is pronounced [iɛ] instead of [iə]), we could have just one inconsistency (1. -e following -i is pronounced [ɛ] instead of [ə].)

Answer (score 3):

Although Wade–Giles uses *-ien*, Zhuyin (1910) uses ㄧㄢ *-ian*, Gwoyeu Romatzyh (1926) has *-ian* for the basic form of first tone, Latinxua Sin Wenz (1931) has *-ian*, and Yale romanization (1943) uses *-yan*. Likewise, pinyin's usage of *-üan* instead of *-üen* for [yɛn] has precedence in Wade–Giles (1892) *-üan*, Zhuyin ㄩㄢ *-üan*, Latinxua Sin Wenz *yan*, and Yale *ywan*.

Yale romanization in particular was supposed to be designed to be intuitive for English speakers to pronounce, which suggests that its *yan* and *ywan* were not pronounced [iɛn] and [yɛn] at the time, but rather [ian] and [yan].

Alternatively, these could be a holdover from Zhuyin. In Zhuyin, pinyin *-ian* is represented as ㄧㄢ *-ian*, and couldn't be represented as ㄧㄣ *-ien*, because that's used for pinyin *-in*.

Pinyin also draws inspiration from Zhuyin in other ways, such as the tone accent marks and the spelling of bopomofo (rather than *buopuomoufuo).

Perhaps Zhuyin could have created a dedicated *-ên* symbol, but overall, Zhuyin is somewhat minimalist in its inventory of finals. For example, it could have made sense to have dedicated letters for *-in* and *-ing*, rather than representing those sounds with *-ien* ㄧㄣ and *-ieng* ㄧㄥ. In fact, the character ㄣ *-en* is derived from 乚 yǐn, even though *yin* and *en* are different syllables.

[image: Bopomofo letters]

Comment: ㄩㄥ (same as -iong, but written as -üeng) is also a weird peculiarity of Zhuyin.

Answer (score 1):

It seems /ian/ can be a valid [broad transcription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_transcription) of (Pinyin) **ian**, but [iɛn] and [ian] can be allophones. Pinyin is best thought of as broad transcriptions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Some Chinese Pinying scholars indeed say 盐 deflect to yien.
2. For most chinese, ju,qu,xu can not be pronouced out. Only xü,jü,qü can work. However, writing ü is more labored than u, so u replaces ü when confusion does not occur.

Comment: What does "盐 deflect to yien" mean?

Comment: The sound of 盐 in Putonghua is indeed close to yien, rather than yan. Some scholars have already stated this in published books

Answer (score 0):

Putonghua is based on one typical Northern dialect. Maybe now southern and northern people read the same character differently, as in [jεn] vs [jan] [in IPA symbol], but the romanization is based on the northern pronunciation.

Answer (score 0):

The the vowel in "an" is pronounced differently depending on the context it occurs in, but the realisations have been analysed differently by different linguists:

> Like the mid vowel, the low vowel has several variants, and there is again some disagreement on their surface values. [...]
>
> In (55) I compare four proposals (the underscore in the top row indicates
> the location of the low vowel; [a] is front in all transcriptions).
>
> (55)
>
> |  | [ j_n] | [ɥ _n] | [ _i]/[ _n] |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | S. Xu ( 1980) | [æ] | [ɐ] | [a] |
> | M. Fu ( 1956) | [ɛ] | [ɛ] | [a] |
> | Chao ( 1968) | [ɛ] | [a] | [a] |
> | Y. Lin ( 1989) | [ɛ] | [a]([ɛ]) | [a] |

- *Phonology of Standard Chinese*, 2.10.3. **The low vowel**

While Chao and Xu make a distinction between "-ian" and "-üan" (as represented in Wade-Giles), Fu treats them as the same (as in Zhuyin and Pinyin). The latter treatment is consistent with Chinese rhyme harmony:

> Similarly, since [an], [uan], [yan], and [iɛn] rhyme, they ought to have the same surface vowel. It is not necessary to distinguish the low vowels in [an], [uan], [yɐn], and [iæn], as S. Xu does, nor the low vowels in [yan] and [iɛn], as Chao does.

- Ibid., 3.5.2 **Rhyming groups**